# Cannot send/receive mail on plesk server

Tags: email, postfix-mta, plesk

I have just had to re-image my server and for some reason, when I do a test connection in outlook, it errors on both send/receive with could not connect to server.

I have checked that both postfix and courier-imap are running on the server and have restarted both just to make sure. I am using plesk 12 and have setup users for the email system, so would appreciate some guidance as to how I can troubleshoot this. Many thanks

**SOLVED**

Reset iptables all good now